# Inconsistent Accessiblity Error in static class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm getting inconsistent accessibility error in the following declaration:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static void GetMyDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
    {  
         dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         // continue to do something
    }
}
```

Anyone know which part of it is causing the error?

Comment: Which part of the code exactly does Visual Studio point to? This code alone compiles correctly assuming nothing else is being done.

Comment: downvoted for not explaining anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 'm going to go out on a limb here and say that the `Dictionary` class this code refers to is not in fact `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`, but some other `Dictionary` that exists in your project. If the accessibility of this class is not `public`, the compiler will complain that you cannot expose to the world the method `GetMyDictionary` if one of its parameters is of a type not accessible to said world.

If this is not the case, then the problem is somewhere else and not in the code you give.

In any case, posting the exact error message would help reduce the guessing.

Comment: Finally I got the error fixed, yea one of my class actually didn't put as public.. thanks!

Comment: If the class you didn't declare public is called `Dictionary<,>`, you should probably rename it.